# Swift not working on Ubuntu based OS

Tags: swift, ubuntu

Followed the instructions on Swift.org to have it working. When I try to check if the install is alright by "`swift --version`", I get:

```
bash: ~/Swift/usr/bin/swift: Permission denied
```

Already tried to use chmod 755 and no improvement. If I try to call "swift" only as well it has the same outcome of course.

What directions to take?

Comment: Did you follow the install process step by step as explained on swift.org? What happened during the install, was there any error message or warning?

Comment: Hi @Moritz as far as I recall, no errors at all. It seems to be some stuff about the system maybe?

Comment: I'll just get on online compiler(s) for as far as necessary. Although, if someone gets to know the  answer, I'll be happy to know. Cheers!